# Changing the visibility of Hidable Datasets in Scatterplots ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I have made this graph using the following configurations and data and want to get rid of the outlined portion of the graph but can not find documentation as it is seemingly default in place for this type of graph:

```
`<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            <script>
                //get the csv data
                const chartData = "/static/csv/result.csv";
                //parse
                // const parseData = d3.csvParse(chartData)
                d3.csv(chartData).then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    const x = data.map(function(d) {
                        return d.Algorithm
                    })
                    const y = data.map(function(d) {
                        return d.Cost
                    })
                    const z = data.map(function(d) {
                        return d.Time
                    })`

                    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

                    const dataForConfig = {
                        // labels: x,
                        datasets: x.map((ds, i) => {
                            return {
                                label: x[i],
                                data: [{
                                    x: y[i],
                                    y: z[i]
                                }],
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                // borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 0, 1)',
                                //I want the border color of a point to depend on the algorithm
                                borderColor: function(context) {
                                    // var index = context.dataIndex;
                                    // var value = context.dataset.data[index];
                                    var type = context.dataset.label;
                                    // console.log('WHATTHEFUCK', type)
                                    return type == "Algorithm" ? 'red' : // draw negative values in red
                                        type == "Knapsack" ? 'blue' : // else, alternate values in blue and green
                                        type == "Recursive Knapsack" ? 'green' :
                                        type == "Static" ? 'purple' :
                                        type == "Dynamic" ? "brown" : 'black'
                                },
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }
                        })
                    }

                    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'scatter',
                        data: dataForConfig,
                        labels: {
                            visible: false
                        },
                        options: {
                            legend: {
                                display: false
                            },
                            scales: {
                                y: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    stepSize: 0.05,
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })
            </script>

[![Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmD3v.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmD3v.jpg)

What options do I have to make not visible for that pseudo-legend/interactive key to go away

Thanks
```

So far I have tried making almost every value in the configuration to be not visible but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

To remove the legend you should disable it (as you partially did but in the wrong config node).

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: false,
  }
...
}
```

or

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
  }
...
}
```